# Get number of specific files in folder with Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, count

I would like to know how to modify my python code in order to get just ONLY the `.wav` files in my folder.  Using the code I have below, returns a count for all the files.

**CODE**

```
import os
import glob

# folder path
dir_path = r'G:/DataSet/Mono'

tree = os.walk(dir_path, topdown=True)
count = len(next(tree)[2])
```

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# folder path
dir_path = r'G:/DataSet/Mono'

count = 0
for r, d, f in os.walk(dir_path, topdown=True):
    for file in f:    
        if file.endswith('.wav'):
            count += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).